# Reverse engineer .so file from android app with radare2

Tags: disassembly, radare2, arm, shared-object

I have a `.so` file from an android app, and I know how to list all functions in `IDA Pro`.

How can I do this with `radare2`?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to show the different functions of a binary file in radare2.

Start by opening the binary file and analyze it.

```
$ r2 -A libdbm64.so
```

---

#### Command: afl

The simplest way to list the functions, is the `afl` command which stands for **a**nalysis **f**unction **l**ist. The command will list all the functions in the binary and print it with four columns: Offset, Number of blocks, Length, and Name.

```
[0x00001ba0]> afl
0x00001ba0    4 50   -> 44   entry0
0x00001ed9    1 114          sym.startWatchDbus
0x00001b70    1 6            sym.imp.g_bus_watch_name
0x00003115    1 43           sym.setItemEnabled
0x00001b60    1 6            sym.imp.dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_bool
0x000033f0    1 9            sym._fini
0x00001f4b    1 20           sym.stopWatchDbus
0x00001a70    1 6            sym.imp.g_bus_unwatch_name
0x000030eb    1 42           sym.setItemLabel

...
...
```

---

#### Command: afll

The `afll` command is more verbose than the `afl` command. It will show more columns and their headers.

```
address            size  nbbs edges    cc cost          min bound range max bound          calls locals args xref frame name
================== ==== ===== ===== ===== ==== ================== ===== ================== ===== ====== ==== ==== ===== ====
0x0000000000001ba0   44     4     4     4   19 0x0000000000001ba0    50 0x0000000000001bd2     0    0      0    1     8 entry0
0x0000000000001ed9  114     1     0     1   30 0x0000000000001ed9   114 0x0000000000001f4b     1    3      3    0    56 sym.startWatchDbus
0x0000000000001b70    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000000000001b70     6 0x0000000000001b76     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.g_bus_watch_name
0x0000000000003115   43     1     0     1   18 0x0000000000003115    43 0x0000000000003140     1    2      2    0    24 sym.setItemEnabled
0x0000000000001b60    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000000000001b60     6 0x0000000000001b66     0    0      0    3     0 sym.imp.dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_bool
0x00000000000033f0    9     1     0     1    5 0x00000000000033f0     9 0x00000000000033f9     0    0      0    0     8 sym._fini
0x0000000000001f4b   20     1     0     1   12 0x0000000000001f4b    20 0x0000000000001f5f     1    0      0    0     8 sym.stopWatchDbus
0x0000000000001a70    6     1     0     1    3 0x0000000000001a70     6 0x0000000000001a76     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.g_bus_unwatch_name
0x00000000000030eb   42     1     0     1   17 0x00000000000030eb    42 0x0000000000003115     1    2      2    0    24 sym.setItemLabel
```

---

#### Command: aflt

The `aflt` command is using the newly introduced Table API in radare2. By default it will return a table of data like this:

```
[0x00001ba0]> aflt
╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ addr        │ size  │ name                                               │ nbbs  │ xref  │ calls  │ cc  │
│─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│ 0x00001ba0  │ 50    │ entry0                                             │ 4     │ 3     │ 0      │ 4   │
│ 0x00001ed9  │ 114   │ sym.startWatchDbus                                 │ 1     │ 0     │ 1      │ 1   │
│ 0x00001b70  │ 6     │ sym.imp.g_bus_watch_name                           │ 1     │ 1     │ 0      │ 1   │
│ 0x00003115  │ 43    │ sym.setItemEnabled                                 │ 1     │ 0     │ 1      │ 1   │
│ 0x00001b60  │ 6     │ sym.imp.dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_bool        │ 1     │ 3     │ 0      │ 1   │
│ 0x000033f0  │ 9     │ sym._fini                                          │ 1     │ 0     │ 0      │ 1   │
│ 0x00001f4b  │ 20    │ sym.stopWatchDbus                                  │ 1     │ 0     │ 1      │ 1   │
│ 0x00001a70  │ 6     │ sym.imp.g_bus_unwatch_name                         │ 1     │ 1     │ 0      │ 1   │
│ 0x000030eb  │ 42    │ sym.setItemLabel                                   │ 1     │ 0     │ 1      │ 1   │
...
...

╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

The Table API allows you to query the data you want to see. For example, if I want to only see Name, Offset, and Size I can do it like this:

```
[0x00001ba0]> aflt name/cols/addr/size
╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ name                                               │ addr        │ size  │
│──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│ entry0                                             │ 0x00001ba0  │ 50    │
│ sym.startWatchDbus                                 │ 0x00001ed9  │ 114   │
│ sym.imp.g_bus_watch_name                           │ 0x00001b70  │ 6     │
│ sym.setItemEnabled                                 │ 0x00003115  │ 43    │
│ sym.imp.dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_bool        │ 0x00001b60  │ 6     │
│ sym._fini                                          │ 0x000033f0  │ 9     │
│ sym.stopWatchDbus                                  │ 0x00001f4b  │ 20    │
│ sym.imp.g_bus_unwatch_name                         │ 0x00001a70  │ 6     │
│ sym.setItemLabel                                   │ 0x000030eb  │ 42    │
...
...
│ fcn.00001930                                       │ 0x00001930  │ 6     │
│ loc.imp.XKeysymToString                            │ 0x00001b50  │ 6     │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

---

### JSON

If you are using radare2 for scripting, it is recommended to use the JSON output of every command. `aflj` will show you a json output with all the functions. I appended the `{}` to make it prettier.

```
[0x00001ba0]> aflj~{}
[
  {
    "offset": 7072,
    "name": "entry0",
    "size": 50,
    "is-pure": "false",
    "realsz": 44,
    "stackframe": 8,
    "calltype": "amd64",
    ...
    ...
  }, {
      ...
  }
```

---

#### Cutter

Finally, if you don't find it comfortable to use the command line for your reverse engineering session. I recommend using [Cutter](https://cutter.re) which is a GUI Reverse Engineering framework powered by radare2 and created by the radare organization.

[image]

By default, you will have a list of functions on the left. You can expand it to reveal more information.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use [this](https://gist.github.com/williballenthin/6857590dab3e2a6559d7) or [this](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/refcard/intro.html) cheat-sheets for `radare2`.

From the document:

`list functions: afl`

Comment: That just returns a bunch of hex. I would want something like the function window output in this tutorial: https://github.com/byteandahalf/MCPE-NativeMods/wiki/4:-Setting-up-IDA

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output

Answer (score 0):

```
0x00000000]> \iE* libjni.so
```

It shows a list of exported function signatures with their absolute address in memory, like this:

```
f sym.fun._Znaj = 0xc5a3f8b5
f sym.fun._ZdaPv = 0xc5a3e579
f sym.fun._ZdlPv = 0xc5a3e575
f sym.fun.__cxa_begin_catch = 0xc5a3ebd5
f sym.fun._ZSt9terminatev = 0xc5a3f4bd
f sym.fun._Znwj = 0xc5a3f861
f sym.var._ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE = 0xc5a97290
f sym.fun.JNI_OnLoad = 0xc5a257a9
f sym.fun.__cxa_allocate_exception = 0xc5a3e655
f sym.fun.__cxa_throw = 0xc5a3f571
f sym.fun.__cxa_free_exception = 0xc5a3e6fd
f sym.fun.__cxa_rethrow = 0xc5a3f5f1
f sym.fun.__cxa_end_catch = 0xc5a3ec65
f sym.var._ZSt7nothrow = 0xc5a94138
f sym.fun._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSsSt9_IdentityISsESt4lessISsESaISsEE5clearEv = 0xc5a36c99
f sym.fun._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSsSt9_IdentityISsESt4lessISsESaISsEE16_M_insert_uniqueISsEESt4pairISt17_Rb_tree_iteratorISsEbEOT_ = 0xc5a36d3d
f sym.fun._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSsSt9_IdentityISsESt4lessISsESaISsEE4findERKSs = 0xc5a38701
f sym.fun._ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEED2Ev = 0xc5a2df71
f sym.fun._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSsSt9_IdentityISsESt4lessISsESaISsEED2Ev = 0xc5a36f11
f sym.fun._ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEE7reserveEj = 0xc5a32455
f sym.fun._ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEE19_M_emplace_back_auxIJSsEEEvDpOT_ = 0xc5a39361
f sym.fun.__cxa_guard_acquire = 0xc5a3f665
f sym.fun.__cxa_guard_release = 0xc5a3f7dd
f sym.fun._ZNSt9exceptionD2Ev = 0xc5a3ed01
...
```